# Is There a Good CMS to Use with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I have a small site I developed for a friend that uses ASP.Net MVC and was wondering if I could hook it up to dotnetnuke or another CMS. Or is doing an admin site using dynamic data?

Comment: Note: I've been using Orchard as the base for CMS for a while now and would definitely recommend it.

Comment: Since then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580475/asp-net-mvc-cms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a list of a few ASP.NET MVC based CMS's. However these are not based on the current release candidate but I think they are a pretty good start.

**N2 Open Source ASP.NET CMS**
http://n2cms.com/

**Oxite**
http://www.visitmix.com/Lab/Oxite

**Hydrogen CMS**
http://www.hydrogencms.net/Home.aspx

Comment: +1 for N2 - I've not downloaded the latest **release** of this, but the up to date code from GoogleCode certainly appears to reference the latest versions of System.Web.Mvc.dll - it's a matter of moments to recompile it anyway, it's also a very good CMS.

Comment: Oxite has a number of "issues" especially around best practices or the potential lack of...

Comment: I've got some hope for the Orchard project.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look to Kooboo ([kooboo.com](http://www.kooboo.com)). A simple to use and flexible CMS based upon ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I just love KooBoo so far. Everythings works exactly as i want it to.

Answer (score 2):

I wish there was a good CMS in MVC. However MVC isn't even RTM yet!
The thing with current .NET CMSs are that they don't handle URLs very well.
I'm hoping a CMS built on MVC will pop up at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Composite C1](http://www.composite.net/C1.aspx). I have developed a few MVC modules for this. The good thing is that you can have both MVC and Web Form modules working side by side in this CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OpenSourceCms.com](http://aspx.opensourcecms.com/), they might have what you're looking for or the demos there might at least help lead you to an answer.

Comment: The .NET version of the site seems to have died.

Answer (score 0):

[Oxite](http://visitmix.com/Lab/Oxite) might be the closest to what you are after at the moment although I think it is more of a blog engine.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the only decent CMS is the one you write yourself. Just the features you want, with no inactive sections, but if you want to have a solid base to start with, try [MVCwCMS](http://www.mvcwcms.com/) (Please note I'm the author).